# I'm not sure I have the correct results following a RISC-V code

Tags: riscv

I have this RISC-V code, and the question is what could be the value in x2 at the end (we don't know what's in x1).

```
ori X2, X0, 0xFFF
slli X2, X2, 12
ori X2, X2, 0xFFF
slli X2, X2, 8
ori X2, X2, 0xFF
xor X2, X2, X1
addi X2, X2, 1
and X2, X2, X1
```

the results I had are (x2 after each step):

```
x2= 111 111 111
x2= 111 111 111 000 000 000 000
x2= 111 111 111 000 111 111 111
x2= 100 011 111 111 100 000 000
x2(*)=100 011 111 111 100 111 111 
x2(final)= (X2`(*)X1+X2X1`+1)=X2`(*)X1
```

and I have 2 questions:

1. is what I did correct?
2. What can I get from the last line if I dont know X1?

Comment: F is 1111 (111 is 7). Try redoing with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first five instructions just end up setting `x2` to `0xffffffff`, so you can replace them with the single instruction `addi x2, zero, -1` or merely the pseudoinstruction `li x2, -1`.

The three last instructions are:

```
xor X2, X2, X1
addi X2, X2, 1
and X2, X2, X1
```

The value assigned to `x2` is *((x1 ^ x2) + 1) & x1*. Since *a ^ b* is equivalent to *~a & b | a & ~b*, then this expression can be expressed as *((~x1 & x2 | x1 & ~x2) + 1) & x1*.

As already explained above, `x2` is, at this point, `0xffffffff` – all *1s* – so, the result of *~x1 & x2* is jus *~x1* and *x1 & ~x2* is all *0s*. The expression above can then be further simplified into ***(~x1 + 1) & x1***.

To sum up, `x2` is assigned the result of the bitwise *and* between `x1` and its *two's complement*. The last three instructions could have been replaced by:

```
neg x2, x1
and x2, x2, x1
```

You may not know `x1`, but you know that `x2` holds, at the end, the result of *(~x1 + 1) & x1*.